# javascript private variable through inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, private-members

I'm stuck with a problem using javascript...
I want to declare a private variable in a class that can't be used from its sublclass...what I've tried is:

```
function Person(){
    var _name
    this.setName = function(name){
        _name = name
    }
    this.getName = function(){
        return _name
    }
}

function GreetingPerson(){
    var self = this;
    self.sayHello = function(){
        console.log(self.getName() + ': "Hello!"');
    }
}

GreetingPerson.prototype = new Person()
GreetingPerson.prototype.contructor = GreetingPerson;

var manuel = new GreetingPerson()
manuel.setName('Manuel');
manuel.sayHello();

var world = new GreetingPerson()
world.setName('World');
world.sayHello();
manuel.sayHello();
console.log(manuel.name)
```

In this way the **name** variable is private, but it is also *static*, so the last wo **sayHello** method calls, will write the same output.
I've tried also changing the **Person** class in this way:

```
function Person(){
    this.setName = function(name){
        this.name = name
    }
    this.getName = function(){
        return this.name
    }
}
```

But in this way it is not longer private.
What is the correct way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Using something like @teddybeard says, you can get it too:

```
function Person(){
    var _name;
    this.setName = function(name){
        _name = name;
    };
    this.getName = function(){
        return _name;
    };
  return this;
}

function GreetingPerson(){
    Person.call(this);
    this.sayHello = function(){
        console.log(this.getName() + ': "Hello!"');
    };
  return this;
}

GreetingPerson.prototype = new Person();
GreetingPerson.prototype.constructor = GreetingPerson;

var manuel = new GreetingPerson();
manuel.setName('Manuel');
manuel.sayHello();

var world = new GreetingPerson();
world.setName('World');
world.sayHello();
manuel.sayHello();
console.log(manuel._name);
```

But I'm not pretty sure if this is actually ok. The problem is that if you don't do something like `Person.call(this);` inside the constructor of `GreetingPerson`, you will not create a new instance of `Person` and it will always use the same `_name` value.

Comment: Yes, it works. I noticed that in this way I don't need to do `GreetingPerson.prototype = new Person()` to make inheritance work

Comment: But if you remove that line, the variable `manuel` will not be an instance of `Person`, it will be just an instance of `GreetingPerson`. If you don't remove it, you should get an object that is an instance of both `Person` and `GreetingPerson`.

Comment: It also seems to work fine without the `return this;` parts. The `Person.call(this);` part seem to be the key here.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter8.html) if you have time. I think this code should work for your purposes of inheritance.

```
function Person() {
    var _name
    this.setName = function(name) {
        _name = name
    }
    this.getName = function() {
        return _name
    }
}

function GreetingPerson() {
    Person.call(this);
    this.sayHello = function() {
        console.log(this.getName() + ': "Hello!"');
    }
}

// taken from Eloquent Javascript
function clone(object) {
    function OneShotConstructor() {}
    OneShotConstructor.prototype = object;
    return new OneShotConstructor();
}

GreetingPerson.prototype = clone(Person.prototype);
GreetingPerson.prototype.contructor = GreetingPerson;

var manuel = new GreetingPerson()
manuel.setName('Manuel');
manuel.sayHello();

var world = new GreetingPerson()
world.setName('World');
world.sayHello();
manuel.sayHello();
console.log(manuel.name)​;​
```